# Show full system.string[] in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, registry, computer-forensics

I am trying to get the wordwheelquery out of HKU into a csv. This is the original output:

```
$reg.PSProvider.Description
MRUListEx    : {3, 0, 0, 0...}
0            : {104, 0, 97, 0...}
1            : {97, 0, 99, 0...}
2            : {107, 0, 117, 0...}
3            : {97, 0, 112, 0...}
```

I want to be able to get each property into their own row under the corresponding heading (property name). So far, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
$reg = Get-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\WordWheelQuery
foreach($reg_properties in $reg.PsObject.Properties){$_properties.Name, $_properties.Value
@{Name=$reg.Name; Expression={$reg.Value}}

MRUListEx
3
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
0
104
0
97
0
108
0
32
0
108
0
101
0
111
0
110
0
97
0
114
0
100
0
0
0
1
97
0
99
0
97
0
100
0
101
0
109
0
105
0
99
0
0
0
2
107
0
117
0
112
0
100
0
102
0
46
0
110
0
101
0
116
0
95
0
104
0
97
0
108
0
45
0
108
0
101
0
111
0
110
0
97
0
114
0
100
0
45
0
103
0
117
0
105
0
116
0
97
0
114
0
45
0
109
0
101
0
116
0
104
0
111
0
100
0
45
0
98
0
111
0
111
0
107
0
45
0
49
0
46
0
112
0
100
0
102
0
0
0
3
97
0
112
0
112
0
100
0
97
0
116
0
97
0
0
0
PSPath
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxx29-xxxxxxx50-54xxxxxxxxx9-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER\WordWheelQuery
PSParentPath
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxx29-xxxxxxx50-54xxxxxxxxx9-1001\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\EXPLORER
PSChildName
WordWheelQuery
PSProvider
```

When exported to a CSV, I still get issues about system.string[] and for the life of me can't get around it.

EDIT: For reference, here is the length of each property

```
PS C:\> $reg.MRUListEx | Measure-Object

Count    : 20
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

PS C:\> $reg.0 | Measure-Object

Count    : 24
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 
  
PS C:\> $reg.1 | Measure-Object

Count    : 18
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 


PS C:\> $reg.2 | Measure-Object

Count    : 94
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

PS C:\> $reg.3 | Measure-Object

Count    : 16
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

Comment: Are the `MRUListEx`, `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` lists all of the same length?

Comment: I don't believe so.. though I'm not 100% sure how to tell (I only started powershell yesterday).

Comment: So... what would a nicely formatted CSV look like?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like each of these properties as a column, and the full length of the property in a row displayed in entirety as opposed to the first 3-4 elements or just 'system.byte[]'.

Comment: So your CSV would only have 1 record, with each of the column values itself being a comma-separated list?

Comment: I probably haven't explained myself well, but imagine 5 columns (MRUListEx | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3), and each should have one row with the corresponding PSObject in its entirety (not hidden like {3, 0, 0, 0...}, but instead the full 20 elements)... if that makes sense.

Comment: I still haven't a clue what your desired output should be. You want the bytes from the REG_BINARY 'MRUListEx' entry in a single column, use `-join`, but WHY would you want to identify them with `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` instead of trying to resolve the SID from the key to username for instance? Please edit your question and show us the exact output you want to get from this.There are serious flaws in your code.. Using a `foreach($thing in $array)` loop you don't have the `$_` automatic variable. For that you need a `ForEach-Object` loop. It then also needs a dot between $_ and the property.